# Dynamically Entering "select" by a string in LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

```
 List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
           string selectQuery = "x";
            var result = from x in list
                         where x > 3
                         select selectQuery;
```

This code will return "xxxx", I want it to return 4 5 6 7.

I want to enter the select dynamically by a string but this code returns the string.
I got a table of conditions, for each condition I want to use a LINQ Query, so I put the select statement in a string table and I want to apply it for each one.

Comment: `var result = from x in list where x > 3 select x`

Comment: Look for the dynamic LINQ library.

Comment: Something like: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XAKgWC ?

Comment: ^^ or better: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3tTG5l

Comment: Yes like this, but can it be linq query ?

Comment: It's just different syntax(-sugar). It does the same.

Comment: So I can write the query in place of the lambda expression? Thankss

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are selecting (returning) the `selectQuery` variable for each item.

Try this:

```cs
var result = from x in list
             where x > 3
             select x;
```

This will return each item of the original list that matches the condition in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: just convert your select query string into a integer, and filter the list with that value:

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1 ,2 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7 };
string selectQuery = "2";

var result = from x in list
             where x > Convert.ToInt32(selectQuery)
             select x;
```

Another way could be

```
 list.Where(x => x > Convert.ToInt32(selectQuery)).ToList()
```

With this way you can do the query with a dynamic value in the string select query.

Comment: The criteria for the select part is not retrieved from a string in your example.

Comment: @AndrewR , the criteria is specified on the selectquery variable in my example, am i wrong?

Comment: the Where criteria is specified in the selectQuery variable.
The Select criteria is just x.
You moved the selectQuery variable from Select to Where.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you can't specify the select criteria in a string. I think the closest you can get is specifying the criteria in a function, and then give the function to the select.